# How to create curl request using Guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I need to perform the following curl request using guzzle:

```
CURL CALL:
==========
curl -i \
-X POST \
-H "X-Version: 1" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: bearer yDqai70hZ8DKD93jy5XtkwPuEf90gU.TUQwZ.ShYjtpy1lkjXvxpbJXViH3ypBIVCAxOyWV" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-d '{"text":"Test Message","to":["27999000001"]}' \
-s \
https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message
```

I have the following:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$result = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.config('clickatell.auth_token'),
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'X-Version' => 1
    ],
    'data' => [
        'to' => $sms->to,
        'text' => $sms->content
    ]
]);
```

But I get this response:

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException]
  Client error: `POST https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
  {"error":{"code":"100","description":"Data malformed","documentation":"http://www.clickatell.com/help/apid
  ocs/error/100. (truncated...)
```

Comment: Why not use their official SDK? https://www.clickatell.com/developers/scripts/php-library/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't encode your data. Error message from your response says that request data isn't valid JSON.

```
$requestData = json_encode([
    'to' => $sms->to,
    'text' => $sms->content
]);

$requestHeaders =  [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.config('clickatell.auth_token'),
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-Version' => 1
];

$result = $client->request(
    'POST', 
    'https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message', 
    [
       'headers' => $requestHeaders,
       'data' => $requestData
    ]
);
```

Also, you can use `post()` method, instead of `request()`

```
$result = $client->post(
    'https://api.clickatell.com/rest/message', 
    [
       'headers' => $requestHeaders,
       'data' => $requestData
    ]
);
```